# How to use new Azure bing api translate with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, api, azure, translate

Before new bing API was released I could simply translate text on my website by using simply Javascript.

It looked like this:

```
      function getTranslations() {
      var languageFrom = $("#firstLanguageHidden").val();
      var languageTo = $("#secondLanguageHidden").val();
      var text = document.getElementById("TextToTranslate").value;

      window.mycallback = function (response) {
          var array = response.Translations;
          var translations = "";
          for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
              translations = translations + array[i].TranslatedText + "\n";
          }
          document.getElementById("results_body").value = translations;
      }

      var s = document.createElement("script");    
      s.src = "http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/GetTranslations?oncomplete=mycallback&appId=7xigXu+M3H/bymbykY/7Us3/UxtSA3w0tq31eFSmUT0=&text=" + text +     "&from=" + languageFrom + "&to=" + languageTo + "&maxTranslations=5";
      document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
  }
```

And it worked just fine.

Now Url from microsoft looks like this:

```
http://api.datamarket.azure.com/Data.ashx/Bing/MicrosoftTranslator/v1/Translate?
```

I have no idea how to translate text on my website just by using javascript. In azure website there are many Keys (secret, etc...) but there isn't any AppId.

Please help me how to do this. My website is wrote in MVC3.

PS: sorry for my english.